# I used different transformations on all the variables in multiple regression analysis

Tags: regression, data-transformation

So, I used different transformations on different variables, to create a normal distribution. I did the multiple linear regression with it. But now I am coming to the part in which I need to interpret the variables. I used Square root transformations and log transformations.

It is about the percentage of migrants in a neighbourhood, the independent variables are the average housing values in those neighbourhoods and the distance to the city center (since the housing value is not corrected for location).
This is the current regression equation.

Sqrt(Migration2022) = 18.267 - 5.260*log(HousingValuex1000) + 0.458*sqrt(BikingDistance) + error term.

Is there anyway to make this interpretable?